# How to pull in files that satisfy a criteria (Say pull Files after a specific date) using Apache Camel SFTP

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-camel

I am using Apache Camel along with Spring MVC. I am doing sftp:// to pull in files from a directory. How could I pull in or process the files based on file creation date later than a given specific date or a Constant date?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified how exactly you want to use the creation date, but there definitely is a way to filter based on last modified date (equivalent to creation date for new files).

You can achieve this using the `filterFile` parameter in the [SFTP component](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.11.x/sftp-component.html). Something like this could work for your use-case: `filterFile=${file:modified} > ${date:now-24h}`. That would include files modified in the past 24h.

You may also want to look at ways to avoid reading files while someone is trying to write in them. Some form of ready-file is a common option i.e. the `doneFileName` parameter.